# How do I mount this .img file in Debian 7 properly?

Tags: debian, filesystems, mount, kali-linux, disk-image

I have an unusual .img file that I wish to mount on my Debian 7 system. I tried `mount` but that does not work:

```
sudo mount -t udf overlay1.img /mnt/vehicle/ -o loop
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Next I tried to determine the partition system in this .img file:

```
sudo fdisk -l overlay1.img

Disk overlay1.img: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcd42b400

Device        Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
overlay1.img1 ?    3892371390 4109164418 216793029 103.4G 72 unknown
overlay1.img2 ?    3287936629 3304577640  16641012     8G  6 FAT16

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Any suggestions on how to mount this file system are welcome. I have only worked with simple .iso mounts before and would like to learn how to mount these as well.

Comment: the output from fdisk seems totally bogus. Try `file overlay1.img` to see what type of file it is.

Comment: `file overlay1.img 
overlay1.img: DOS/MBR boot sector`

Answer (score 1):

If this is a normal "single partition" image then just try to mount it normally and let the OS auto-guess the type:

```
mount -o loop -r overlay1.img /mnt/vehicle
```

If this is a raw disk image, including all the partition data then you can use `losetup` to add the device

```
losetup loop0 overlay1.img
```

That will setup `/dev/loop0`.  You can verify it's been setup with

```
losetup -l
```

Now you need to setup the partitions:

```
kpartx -av /dev/loop0
```

This will create the entries such as `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` and `/dev/mapper/loop0p2`.

Now you can mount them

```
mount -r /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/vehicle
```

When you have finished:

```
umount /mnt/vehicle
kpartx -dv /dev/loop0
losetup -d loop0
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `sudo kpartx -av /dev/loop0
device-mapper: resume ioctl on loop0p1 failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop0p1
device-mapper: resume ioctl on loop0p2 failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop0p2`

Comment: That confirms the initial `fdisk` output - it _looks_ corrupt; it's a 4Mb file but with a 100Gb partition inside?  Looks wrong...  You might want to examine it further with a hexdump (eg `xxd`) and look at the contents.